# Dynamically add page numbers to PDF reports generated from tableau

Tags: pdf, tableau-api

I have PDF reports that are generated from Tableau after regular intervals with different **number of pages** each time . I want to add **page numbers** to these reports each time . How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can `Edit Title` and there use insert dropdown to add `Page Number` which will add the page number to every sheet.

Comment: Doesn't work in multiple dashboards . I have downloaded the pdf but then how do i add page numbers to that . I mean what is the way to automate the process of adding page numbers to the pdf ?

Comment: Your question is incomplete... can you add your design and how are you pulling PDF